# web focus %0 access denied error

Tags: php, webfocus

Had anybody ran into the problem of "403:Access Denied" while trying to use wild card '%' in the text box of web focus for pattern matching? for example : trying to find courses that follows ENGL001 pattern I used ENGL%00 that throws "access denied error" but using ENGL__00% works. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: In my opinion it s due to  %00. It s the null byte character.

Comment: I know that's how their language reads %00. Is there any way in web focus to by pass this and read the text as it is entered by user?

Comment: I don t know.I m not sure at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out 2 solutions 1) either you comment the line 
    PROHIBITED_CHARACTERS_URL_ENCODED DATA="%00" 
under the folder “/config/request-nbi-validation-table.xml file or

2) Create a HTML report, and read in % as ~ and in fex file read that back to % using java script